# How to save Outlook attachments in subfolders based on Subject string

Tags: vba, outlook, save, attachment, subject

I'm very new to VBA but any help would be hugely appreciated!

THE PROBLEM:

I get a series of quotes from work, which are in email form but include 1 or more attachment files. I want them to automatically be stored under a folder as follows:

C: \ Users \ username \ Desktop \ Quotes \ ######## \

The ######### is given in the subject line of the email, in the form: "Standard Quote ########".

So far I've got how to automatically save the files in the one \ Quotes \ folder, but I don't know how to extract the numerical string ######## from the subject title of the email...

```
Public Sub saveQuote(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim myItem As MailItem

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Quotes"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & myItem.Subject & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If the numeric value is the last segment of the subject, this should be easy. Try `Right function` or better yet, `Split function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as I've commented:
If the numeric part is fixed at 8 characters

```
Dim myqoute

myqoute = Right(itm.Subject, 8)
```

if not, use `Split`

```
myqoute = Split(itm.Subject, " ")(Ubound(Split(itm.Subject, " ")))
```

Then use it in your filename.
If however you want to create a directory (sub folder for each qoute number) use `MkDir`.

```
MkDir "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\Qoutes\" & myqoute
objatt.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\ & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\Qoutes" & _
            myqoute & "\" objatt.DisplayName
```

I used `Environ` function for user flexibility.
Hope this helps.